# Custom exception in java

Tags: java, exception

I have a simple exception and I don't know how to deal with it. My question is what should I do in main?

I know I should create an `Exception Class` but that's a simple example to understand how should the exceptions be treated in main.

In main I want do display a message and exit the program and I don't understand how to do it.

```
public void addProfessor() throws Exception {
    if(professor) {
        throw new Exception(" prof already exists");
    }
    else {
        professor=true;
        System.out.println("\n--- addProfessor ---");
        System.out.println("Professor: " + professor);
        superState=SuperState.OPEN;
        System.out.println(superState);
        subState=SubState.ASSIGNED;
        System.out.println(subState);

    }
}


try {
    C.addProfessor();
    C.addProfessor();//here an exception should be displayed because I should have only one professor
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {

}
```

Comment: 1: don't throw and catch generic exceptions. They're typed for a reason. 2: it depends: do you want to give your users the opportunity to try again? Do you want to just exit? What do you want to do?

Comment: what exactly are you asking?

Comment: Depends.  Do you want your program to just end? Or do you want your user to try again? Or do you want to do something else? There is simply not enough information to answer this question.

Comment: I want to display a message and give the users the opportunity to try again

Comment: try what again? Edit your question to explain what exactly you want to do, and what issue you have

Comment: edit: I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your example looks like the exception you are trying to use is thrown in standard buisness flow.
It's good practice to keep exceptions to handle really exceptional cases, and not use it in a program flow.

If it's just an example then:

**First:** (as mentioned in one of comments) better create your own exception (just derive for example from RuntimeException if you want unchecked
or from Exception for checked one) - then you will not catch some other unexpected exception by accident.

**Second:** when you catch the exception then you have a choice what to do:

1. do some cleanup & rethrow
2. just log it
3. you can also re-try if it makes sense (in your example it does not, because re-trying will just throw another exception - unless the profesor has been removed by another thread)

When you catch the exceptin instead of `e.printStackTrace();` you can get a message from the exception or even (as you created your own meaningful exception) you already know the root cause and can just display it to the user.

just an ilustration:

```
catch(ProfessorAlreadyExistsException e) {
    System.out.println("Professor already exists");
}
```

Comment: And in finally what should I put? Or when I should put something in finally?

Comment: you don't need finally in your case.
You put there code that is supposed to be ALWAYS executed - no matter if there was exception or not. (for example resource cleanup - like file closing etc...)

Answer (score 0):

To create a custom `Exception` you need to create a class that extends `Exception`. For example as follow:

```
public class ProfessorException extends Exception {
    public ProfessorException(String msg) {
        super(msg); 
    }
}
```

Then you need to use this `ProfessorException` in your code:

```
  public void addProfessor() throws ProfessorException {
      if(professor) {
         throw new ProfessorException(" prof already exists");
      }
      ...
   }

   ...




try {
    C.addProfessor();
    C.addProfessor();//here an exception should be displayed because I should have only one professor
} catch (ProfessorException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {  // Note that finally block is not needed here because it does nothing

}
```

If you want to display a message on standard output instead of printing the stack trace you can do that:

```
try {
   C.addProfessor();
   C.addProfessor();//here an exception should be displayed because I should have only one professor
} catch (ProfessorException e) {
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: And if i have 2 or more exceptions, i should a class that extends Exception for every exception that i want to handle?

Comment: You can decide to add new specific classes for each Exception of if the exception is of the same "type" you can throw the same exception with a different message or you can add parameters to the "ProfessorException" to distinguish between two different cases of the same exception.